# Google Hangouts on Mavericks in Safari or Chrome: how to adjust audio settings?

Tags: macos, safari, audio, google-chrome, google-hangouts

I could have sworn that Google Hangouts *used* to provide a settings panel for testing and adjusting audio settings.  I know I've used it in the past: it was a facility that showed volume levels, let you play a test sound, etc.  Now I cannot find it anywhere.  After starting a video Hangout in the latest Safari or Chrome on OSX 10.9.5, clicking on the gear icon in the top portion of the screen brings up a dialog that has only the following options:

[image]

The only feature now is "Play test sound"; none of the submenus, or elsewhere in Hangouts as far as I can see, is there any ability to adjust volume, test that the microphone is working properly, etc.

I feel I'm either a complete idiot now or dreamt the whole thing. What am I missing? How do I adjust sound settings for Google Hangouts? I really believe there used to be a more extensive preferences/settings panel than the one (the only one) I can find now.

Answer (score 1):

AFIK it is only possible

**(Hangouts On Air only)** Audio setting:

Whether you’re performing your favorite song in a Hangout On Air or just talking with a few friends, you can optimize the audio by going to your settings and choosing the sound setting that works best for you.